# Need help in JavaScript , openWindow ();

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to run the following JavaScript program,

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x;
  if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
    x = "You pressed Ok!";
  } else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

But I really need is not just saying "You pressed Ok" instead of that it need to open a link. Help me please.

I hope

```
openWindow("http://fb.com")
```

this line will help, but don't know where to place it and make a working program.

Comment: You should use `window.open("http://www.google.com")` and just place it where your `x = "You pressed Ok!";` is.

Comment: A simple search of the internet for "how to open a window in javascript" would have found the answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (confirm("Press a button!")) {
    window.open('www.google.com')
}
```

Comment: FYI, `if (confirm(...))` is identical to `if (confirm(...) == true)`, because the _condition_ statement inside an `if` is evaluated as a boolean expression, and checking whether any given boolean expression `e` for `e == true` is essentially the same as the expression itself.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your function and place your `openWindow()` call inside it. Because I don't know what your `openWindow()` function does, I would use `window.open()`:

```
function myFunction() {
  window.open("http://fb.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
var x;
if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {


location.href = "http://www.google.com";

} else {

x = "You pressed Cancel!";

}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```